# join based on one column and use value from another col

Tags: sql

I have a table `themeNames`that looks like this:

```
themeName        id
firstTheme       3
secondTheme      5
NewTheme         9
HelloTheme       8
```

I want to join it with another table `updated` that looks like this:

```
val      newName       oldName 
1        first         firstTheme
2        second        secondTheme
```

I want to create a new column in the first table by joining based on the oldNames/themeName such that if a themeName is not present, then that row's value should be empty.

The final result should be look like this:

```
themeName       id      finalName
firstTheme       3      first
secondTheme      5      second 
NewTheme         9      NULL
HelloTheme       8      NULL
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a left join between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT
    t.themeName,
    t.id,
    u.newName AS finalName
FROM themeNames t
LEFT JOIN updated u
    ON u.oldName = t.themeName;
```